# matplotlib: Rescale colors of imshow after zooming in

Tags: zooming, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 2D field using imshow. I'd like the colors to rescale after zooming in so I can see more detail.

The only solution I know of is to take the coordinates of the box returned by a RectangleSelector event and replot a submatrix of the original data. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of searching, I couldn't find any alternatives. However, implementing this with the RectangleSelector and just replotting a submatrix of the original data turned out to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use interactive plotting with `pylab.ion` and update the plot using the `draw` command instead of the `show` command. Then, in your code, make a while loop that prompts you for keyboard input. At each iteration, if you enter `-1` the program exists. Otherwise, maybe you enter something like `x1, y1, x2, y2` which depicts a bounding box you want to zoom in on in your coordinate axes, and then your program makes a new figure, re-computes the relevant data onto new grids involving the input `x1, y1, x2, y2`, and re-plot. If you save all the input coordinates, you could even have a special keyboard input for "undo" (as in, zoom back out to where I just was). This should not be very hard to implement, the only question will be how severe the computation is to re-sample your image onto the zoomed-in grid.